# Firebase : How to Check Count of Users on a Specific App Version from Firebase Console

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I would like to know how to check count of Users on a specific app version from firebase console (**30 day active**). For Example, our mobile app has 5 versions/releases. 
Need the result as per following.

```
Version       Count
3.1.5        250021
3.1.4         45332
3.1.3          4452
3.1.2            24
3.1.1             0
```

**-- Update**

I managed to get some information in latest updated version for firebase console where app version wise dashboard was available.

Is it possible to get some specific app page field value for users running their app on any specific version e.g. 3.1.2 for past 30 days, 7 days and last day ??

Comment: Try Crashlytics in firebase.

Comment: Did u try firebase analytics to your app?

Comment: Have you tried BigQuery ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Firebase Analytic's console is severely limited in what it can do.

Connect your Firebase account to google analytics and use "Reporting Beta" and you'll be able to build this exact report.

Here is a screenshot showing the options I selected to put it together.

[image]